# Goutte: Clicking on links using class names

Tags: php, laravel, web-crawler, goutte

I'm trying to scrape from an e-commerce website and text on links is different for all items. But they have a common class name. Is it possible to click on them using class names with Goutte? Or will it work only with the text on them.

Answer (score 0):

Goutte uses Symfony's [DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) and [CssSelector](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html) components to navigate the returned document. These provide some fairly powerful tools to search using either XPath or CSS selectors.

An example of selecting all links by class "red":

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.symfony.com/blog/');
$links = $crawler->filter('a[class="red"]');
```